# UITableView not populating when Subview of Scollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5, uiscrollview

A bit more background to it: the XIB has a `UITableView` as a subview of a `UIScrollView`, 
the `UIScrollView` is a subview of a `UIView`. The table does not populate when it is a subview of the `UIScrollView`. I am an iOS beginner. So any help would be great.

Comment: Check your dataSource and delegate connections.

Comment: Hi @Eimantas, I have connected the firstTableView by control dragging to files owner. I also have "self.firstTableView.dataSource = self; and self.firstTableView.delegate" above the [super viewDidLoad]; in the viewDidLoad method. Does this sound ok? Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You should add the `[self.firstTableView reloadData]` if it's not the main tableView of your controller.

Comment: Thank you @Eimantas tried placing that after [super viewDidLoad], and it did not work. What do you mean by "in the main tableView" apologies for my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are returning a non-zero value in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method. Check if you are doing something in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` (you should create and fill them with some info).
Btw, had you implemented them?

> What do you mean by "in the main tableView" apologies for my lack of understanding.

In `UITableViewController` you have one `UITableView` which is the main view (`self.view` and `self.tableView` properties) of this VC. So it calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` automatically. If you're adding other `UITableView`s or placing them in `UIViewController` you should call this method by yourself in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks @efpies,I'm stuck 24 hrs. I have And have implemented the above checks, I NSLog the value for `tableView:numberOFRowsInSection`, and its positive. And yes I have populated them. I really am baffled. I have the code [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3gn1PhDx). With now the addition of `self.firstTableView.delegate = self` and `self.firsttableView.dataSource = self;` and `[self.firstTableView reloadData]` in after the `[super viewDidLoad] in the viewDidLoad method. I also have the firsttableView ctrl dragged to the files owner for the datasource and delegate.

Comment: I checked your code and launched it in iPhone Simulator — it works. You have a bug in other place. Please, upload a whole project directory in zip archive and post a link.

Comment: Hi @efpies, [Here is the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hjf607ao2lg5gzo/stackoverflow.zip) as requested. Thanks a million. Really appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Eimantas just thought I'd let you know the link is up incase you're interested. Cheers

Comment: Problem Solved. It was the autosizing constraints set for the tableView in the IB.